# Apache Rewrite Rule to support with, without slash and index.htm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to 301 redirect users from my old website to new website. I was working on the apache Rule to redirect all these 3 formats to new website :

http://mypreviousdomain.com/news/RSS

http://mypreviousdomain.com/news/RSS/

http://mypreviousdomain.com/news/RSS/index.htm

TO

http://newdomain.com/news/feed.html

```
RewriteRule ^/news/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ http://newdomain.com/news/feed.html [L,R=301]
```

Kindly suggest what should be the appropriate rule to handle the situation.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach for it,

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/([\w]+)?/?(index.htm)?/?$ http://newdomain.com/news/feed.html [L,R=301]
```